# Copy Rows to SQL Server Table using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql-server, error-000210

I want to copy a table in my GDB to a table in MSSQL server 2012.

I'm using the "Copy Rows" tool in ModelBuilder, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Database Connections\Connection to 
<Server>.sde\<DB>.dbo.<Table>
DBMS table not found
DBMS table not found
Failed to execute
```

The Table exists, and I can even select it as the Output Table in the Copy Rows tool GUI.